# The way I should parse RSS feed like other applications?

Tags: c#, xml, rss, standards, w3c

I am thinking now how the rss applications are parsing the feeds, basically if I just want to parse XML from the feed I will use XMLReader

http://content.warframe.com/dynamic/rss.php

Based on this feed I will get exception about illegal path (this is less important), BUT I can put this link to another application (link at the bottom) and it will work...

There is w3c validator which shows many error
http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcontent.warframe.com%2Fdynamic%2Frss.php

If this rss feed really have so many "errors", why it is working with other applications? On example when i put it into:
http://feed.mikle.com/

Comment: I hope this answer will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10399441/2115584

Comment: Only if I can create sindication by using String, simply I can't work with XMLReader class cuz it won't accept the rss code